# Optimize Partitioning for Dual-boot system (Windows 10 & Kubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, kubuntu, windows-10

### Context:

Hi,
So I recently had the chance to clean install my old computer and decided to opt for dual-booting. My computer has a *240GB m.2 SATA SSD* and a *1TB HDD*. I want to optimize the performance of the machine therefore everything that requires higher read/write speed I would throw into the SSD and the rest in HDD. For **Windows 10** it was pretty straight forward: system, online games, UE4,... -> gets put into the "Win10" partition (or C drive in Windows) on the SSD; and the rest such as offline games, pictures, documents,... goes into the "WinHD" partition on the HDD.

1. [SSD partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBhKv.png)
2. [HDD partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyWRP.png)

### Question:

Here comes the part that has had me scratching my head for the last hour: *How to set up a partitioning scheme for **Kubuntu 20.04** with the same optimization idea as the Windows 10?*
.
To my understanding, the Linux file system is very different from Windows (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlpRb.png) and an application's contents gets handled by the package manager =>

1. *I got 510GB on the HDD exclusively for Kubuntu, how should I partition it?* (As you can see in the given pictures, when i intsalled Kubuntu I just chucked them all together)
2. *Where should I mount that/those partition(s)?* (As you can see I mounted them on the */home* directory and tbh I don't think that was the right call... For some reason my computer has been running with this rather distracting "Rrrrr...rrrr" noice which might be from the HDD or the old wonky fans (which is still bad since that would indicate that the system is under load eventhough I only have chrome open))

I'm new to Ubuntu but would like to use it as my main OS so I really want to optimize everything from the get go. ***Please help me*** :<

---

### Unrelated questions:

Here are some unrelated questions that I would be looking into myself but if anyone can answer for me that would be great.

1. I would be using Kubuntu for coding, video editing, photoshop and some game design. Is 80GB on that SSD *not enough*, *enough* or *more than enough*? I'd prefer to move around 15-20 GB to Windows if can.
2. Am I the only one that's having this [blurry text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5vhq.jpg) problem and does anyone know how to fix it?
3. How do I make the hotkey for Kubuntu's default terminal (Konsole) open a different terminal (Tilix)? I've already followed [this](https://itsfoss.com/change-default-terminal-ubuntu/) guide to make tilix my default terminal, however pressing `ctr+alt+T` still opens Konsole.

---

***Thank you for spending your time helping me***

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only. I suggest that you search/research your questions before asking.  Please note that questions that solicit opinions are not on topic. https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Looks like you are ok, why do you think it needs "optimization"? The Kubuntu system is on the DDS, the home partition is on the HDD, looks good to go.